# Mapping Ctrl-Z in insert mode?

Tags: key-bindings

I often <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> to the command line. Is there a way to do that in response to hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> in insert mode?

The `iabbrev` command does not seem to work.

Comment: How does this work for you: `inoremap <c-z> <esc>:stop<cr>` ? Or `inoremap <c-z> <esc><c-z>` See `:h CTRL-Z`

Comment: Works great.  Please make this into an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `:h CTRL-Z` as inspiration, the following solutions can be cooked:

```
:inoremap <c-z> <esc>:stop<cr>
```

or (shorter & literally closer):

```
:inoremap <c-z> <esc><c-z>
```