# Mapping Ctrl-Caret in insert mode?

Tags: key-bindings, plugin-conque

This is similar to [a previous question re: Ctrl-Z](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6134/mapping-ctrl-z-in-insert-mode). The context is different though: I use a bash shell window, in which I am in insert mode.
Hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd> in this mode means that I probably meant to switch to my other buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be very similar to the linked question:

```
inoremap <C-^> <Esc><C-^>
```

This just makes it so that if you type `<C-^>` in insert mode it goes to normal mode and does the command there instead.

See [`:help map-overview`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#map-overview) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

[Tumbler41](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/12096/mapping-ctrl-caret-in-insert-mode/12112#12112) answer is partially incorrect. Use of  `<Esc>` is discouraged in favor of `<C-o>`, so you should use this line instead:

```
imap <C-^> <C-o><C-^>
```

although both are fine in your case.

However, for the educational purposes let's consider this example from my old .vimrc:

```
map <F5> :nohl<CR>
imap <F5> <Esc><F5>
```

After pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> two thing will happen beside turning off highlights:

- you will exit insert mode
- cursor moves to the left

Also notice, that pressing <kbd>i</kbd> to reenter insert mode doesn't move cursor back to the original position, so you need to press <kbd>→</kbd> to get it back to where it was before. I personally found it incredibly annoying.

After changing my example to:

```
map <F5> :nohl<CR>
imap <F5> <C-o><F5>
```

all of those problems disappear.

You can read more about `<C-o>` on the [wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Use_Ctrl-O_instead_of_Esc_in_insert_mode_mappings).